how to produce bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than with git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than?
With
$ java -jar bfg-1.12.15.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M .

We remove files bigger than 10M that are not anymore in the working copy
I'm trying to get the same result with git filter-repo with no success.
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M

remove any file bigger than 10M even if it's in the working copy ;(
